# SFML stuck on main function exit

Tags: c++, sfml

In SFML, when the `main` function exits, my game stucks without responding to any events. Is there a way to kill the main thread using some WinAPI functions?

I can't give the minimal example code, because my project is big enough, and some minimal examples don't stuck.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The WIN32 API have functions to forcibly kill threads. I wouldn't recommend it though, try to signal the thread(s) in some other way to let them clean up and exit in a nice manner instead.

Comment: Is `return 0` nice enough? Because as the debugger says, it goes up to some functions to pass the return value, and stuck on `exit(mainret)`.

Comment: How do you determine "stuck"? Provide your minimal example code. How do you start the application? What if you run it through a debugger and pause it once it's stuck.

Comment: OMG. When going step by step in the debugger it goes up to `exit(mainret)`, when paused it stop at `MutexImpl::lock()` in SFML.

Comment: Provide your minimal example code and information on your compiler and your OS and from where you got SFML.

Comment: If the minimal example doesnt show the issue then the issue is clearly caused somewhere else in your "large project". Chances are its nothing to do with SFML and more likely a careless use of mutexs/threads

Answer (score 1):

Are you closing the window before exiting the program? Just returning 0 from the main function won't do that for you.

//
App.close();

return 0;

//

Answer (score 0):

Okay, SFML as usually can't do something without context, so I made my sf::Font in my Game class a pointer, and initialize it after window is created. That fixed the bug